# Obtener los nombres de las tablas de una BD en postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Estoy haciendo un script para auditar las tablas de una base de datos postgres, para lo cual necesito obtener los nombres de las tablas que están en la base de datos y de esta manera poder recorrerlos a través de un arreglo, ya que la base de datos tiene muchas tablas y no quiero hacerlo a mano.

**¿Existe una consulta en postgresql para obtener los nombres de las tablas que componen la base de datos?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basado en la documentación oficial de PostgreSQL acerca de la [información del esquema de base de datos](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/infoschema-tables.html), lo que se podría hacer es consultar la información de las tablas almacenada en `information_schema` ya que en esta existe una tabla llamada `tables` en la cual se encuentra el nombre de cada tabla que compone la base de datos. La consulta sería la siguiente:

```
SELECT table_name --seleccionamos solo la columna del nombre de la tabla
FROM information_schema.tables --seleccionamos la información del esquema 
WHERE table_schema='public' --las tablas se encuentran en el esquema publico
AND table_type='BASE TABLE'; --tiene que ser del tipo table ya que aqui se listan tambien las vistas
```

De esta manera se obtendrian los nombres de las tablas que componen la base de datos, generando un resultado que se puede iterar en algun lenguaje de programación.

Answer (score 3):

otra opción muy util y probado ; presente la misma duda que tu

```
=>\dt
```

o puede ser

```
=>SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables;
```

merito a https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769683/show-tables-in-postgresql

Answer (score 3):

Concretamente, si lo que buscas es un procedimiento para realizar cualquier acción espontánea con esas tablas, yo suelo construir un script al momento con una estructura muy fácil y no es necesario crear una función, ejecutarla y luego borrarla.

Usando la consulta de Juan Pinzón, el script quedaría como sigue:

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
    _schema text;
    _table text;
BEGIN
    FOR _schema, _table IN
        SELECT table_schema, table_name
        FROM information_schema.tables
        -- No filtro por esquema 'public' porque yo uso muchos más esquemas
        WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
    LOOP
        -- En este bloque LOOP puedes introducir tu código para hacer lo que quieras
        -- con las tablas
        -- Usando las variables _schema, _table
        RAISE NOTICE 'Código a ejecutar con %, %', _schema, _table;
    END LOOP;

END
$$
;
```